# Bootstrap carousel display is incorrect

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Currently using Bootstrap 3.xx to make a website, having some trouble getting a carousel to work properly.

Site version - [www.solo-fusion.com/test/index.htm](http://www.solo-fusion.com/test/index.htm)

```
<div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide col-lg-8 col-offset-2">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="//placehold.it/500x500" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
       <div class="item">
         <img src="//placehold.it/500x500/EEEEEE" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
       <div class="item">
         <img src="//placehold.it/500x500/FEFEFE" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#Carousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#Carousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

This is the segment of code I'm using, along with this for the CSS

```
.carousel {
    height: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.carousel-caption {
    z-index: 10;
}
.carousel .item {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here, but the results of this are a bit funky.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3XV0.png

Any help would be good help :)

**UPDATE** I've managed to somehow get it to start scrolling now, doing something with the following JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Carousel').carousel({
    //options here
    });
});

</script>
```

P.S. still broken though :L

**UPDATE #2**

Here's the part of the jkit.css for the carousel because someone suggested it might be what's causing it.

```
div.carousel {
overflow: hidden;
pointer-events: none;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
}

div.carousel-item {
float: left;
width: 20%;
height: 150px;
background: #E01B49;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 200%;
}

div.carousel-item div {
padding: 20px;
border: 1px #fff solid;
height: 110px;
}

a.jkit-carousel-prev, a.jkit-carousel-next {
width: 40px;
background: #eee;
border: 1px #999 solid;
color: #333;
padding: 4px;
cursor: pointer;
cursor: hand;
margin-top: 10px;
text-align: center;
user-select: none;
}

a.jkit-carousel-prev:hover, a.jkit-carousel-next:hover {
background: #fff;
border: 1px #666 solid;
color: #000;
}

a.jkit-carousel-prev {
float: left;
}

a.jkit-carousel-next {
float: right;
}
```

Comment: It's something else because the bootply with your code works well : http://www.bootply.com/123368

Comment: I've been practically bashing my head on the desk for hours trying to work out what this could be.

Comment: @TheLittlePig - Cool. I learned something new today

Comment: It seems that Bootstrap styles are colliding with `jkit.css`

Comment: Should I copy paste the carousel parts of the jkit.css?

Comment: I suggest you comment the carousel parts or the entire jkit.css itself and see if the carousel displays correctly.

Comment: @EmanuelSaringan I've tried commenting out both the jkit.css carousel parts and the whole thing, didn't work, then tried doing the same with the carousel.css that I mentioned earlier in the post. Still no luck.

Comment: Always start here: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.solo-fusion.com%2Ftest%2Findex.htm&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: @WesleyMurch None of the errors on their seem to have anything to do with what might be causing this to happen though, but most of those errors seems to be false anyway...

Comment: @Megaben Sure missing alt is not related, but the stray open/end tag errors are ones you need to resolve. The errors are not "false", it's actually looking at your source code. Dismiss my help if you want, but I'm telling you: you can't debug broken HTML.

Comment: @WesleyMurch I never meant to say that I wasn't going to look into these errors, it was just from my first look it seemed like most of them were complaining about missing starting <p> tags or extra </div> tags, and after counting them all out I can see most of them, mainly the <p> tags do actually have a match for the pair, although Dreamweaver is supposed to highlight them yellow if they don't have a match or something.

TL;DR = my head hurts.

Answer (score 0):

One way where it seems to work :

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/123416

**CSS** :

```
div.carousel {
overflow: hidden;
//pointer-events: none;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
}

div.carousel .item {        // <--- HERE
float: left;
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
background: #E01B49;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 200%;
}

div.carousel .item img {   // <--- HERE
display:inline;
  height:100%;
}

a.jkit-carousel-prev, a.jkit-carousel-next {
width: 40px;
background: #eee;
border: 1px #999 solid;
color: #333;
padding: 4px;
cursor: pointer;
cursor: hand;
margin-top: 10px;
text-align: center;
user-select: none;
}

a.jkit-carousel-prev:hover, a.jkit-carousel-next:hover {
background: #fff;
border: 1px #666 solid;
color: #000;
}

a.jkit-carousel-prev {
float: left;
}

a.jkit-carousel-next {
float: right;
}
```

Comment: Kept everything the same but turned it pink for me? O.o

Comment: Just tried doing it exactly the same a 2nd time, now I can click through the slides, but they're all aligned to the bottom left now?